# Can Kong return your RESTful API request in parameterized form?

Tags: restful-url, kong

I know it takes restful api and we can add some plugins on it but for my purpose I need the parameterized form of API from getkong server? Is this possible? and if yes please let me know how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand your question, but you can retrieve the APIs you have added on Kong using the admin API, like:

```
curl localhost:8001/apis
```

https://getkong.org/docs/latest/admin-api/#list-apis